# Delete meta_values from meta_key MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm so bad in MySQL, I need to update values `first_name` and `last_name` as blank in a table. I was trying to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM nomtable WHERE meta_key = 'first_name'
```

But I'm afraid of making a mess...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE nomtable
SET  meta_value = NULL -- or ''
WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name')
  -- AND user_id = ?;
```

What do you mean by setting as blank: empty string `''` or `NULL`?

You can add `user_id` if you don't want to update all values, but for specific user.

Comment: @NathanMeyer use `NULL` then

Comment: Thanks for helping, but your SQL request return that : 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM nomtable WHERE meta_key IN ( 'first_name' , 'last_name' )' at line 2

Comment: @NathanMeyer This is not my query? `FROM nomtable`?

Comment: @NathanMeyer Did you use my query or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysql **Update** or Try this query

```
UPDATE nomtable
SET  meta_value = ''
WHERE meta_key ='first_name' OR meta_key ='last_name'
```